# How to animate both the horizontal and vertical radii of border-top-right-radius using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, jquery-animate

Is it possible to animate this:

```
border-radius: 0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 90px 90px;
```

to this:

```
border-radius: 120px 120px 0px 0px / 90px 90px 0px 0px;
```

Using jQuery?

I've tried the following, but cannot get it to work:

```
$('div.smile').animate({
    borderTopLeftRadius: "120px 90px",
    borderTopRightRadius: "120px 90px",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: "0px",
    borderBottomRightRadius: "0px"
});
```

I realise that this is because I can only animate one property value at a time... Is there some way I can break down `borderTopLeftRadius` into its two radius components, e.g. `borderTopLeftRadiusHorizontal` and `borderTopLeftRadiusVertical`?

I will accept a method using either pure jQuery or a jQuery plugin as the correct answer.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/9pASU/19/

Many thanks! :)

## Update

I think knowing the context of what I am trying to achieve as an end result is important here... I want to be able to dynamically change the length/duration of the animation based on other events - preferably even while it is mid-animation i.e. I want to be able to speed up, slow down or stop the animation before, after or while it is happening.  I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I'm dreaming, but if anyone can share their experiences I'd appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use css3 and transtion:

animate from:

```
div.smile {
    /* your codes */
    border-radius: 0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 90px 90px;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all;
    -moz-transition: 2s all;
}
```

to:

```
div.smile.animated {
    border-radius: 120px 120px 0px 0px / 90px 90px 0px 0px;
}
```

js:

```
$this.find('div.smile').addClass('animated');
```

[see this](http://jsfiddle.net/9pASU/20/)

Comment: that's great :) It does answer my question, but unfortunately it doesn't leave me better off. The main reason I wanted .animate() is that I want to be able to dynamically change the time of the animation based on other events. I also want to be able to speed up, slow down or stop the animation while it is happening based on other events. Is this possible with the method you described?

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/9pASU/23/ for more control you can use css animation. see link: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp